# linking assembly and c problem

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, assembly, masm

Trying to understand how to link a function that is defined in a struct, the function is in the assembly code, and am trying to call it from c. I think am missing a step cause when I call the function, I get an unresolved external symbol...

```
;Assembly.asm
.686p
.mmx
.xmm
.model flat

include Definitions.inc

.code

?Initialize@Foo@@SIXPAUFee@@@Z proc
    jmp $
?Initialize@Foo@@SIXPAUFee@@@Z endp

end



//CFile.c
struct Fee
{
   signed long id; 
}

struct Foo
{
   static void Initialize(Fee *);
}


int startup(Fee * init)
{
  Foo::Initialize(init); //<-- This is unresolved
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to expose an asm function to C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assembly code defines a function whose decorated name decodes to

```
public: static void __fastcall Foo::InitializeCurrentCpu(struct Fee *)
```

As obtained through the undname.exe utility.  Foo::InitializeCurrentCpu() won't be a match for Foo::Initialize(), the name doesn't match.  Nor does the calling convention.

Write this code in C++ first and look at the .map file for the correct decorated name.  Or declare the function with extern "C" to suppress C++ decoration.

Comment: just realise I made a typo its ?Initialize@Foo@@SIXPAUFee@@@Z proc and not ?InitializeCurrentCpu@Foo@@SIXPAUFee@@@Z proc

Comment: You still have a mismatch on the calling convention.

Comment: Where exactly do I make the change? In the Foo struct? should the format be exactly like the sample you wrote it... I am getting something like public: static void __cdecl Foo::Initialize(struct Fee *)

Comment: Worked... I just needed to add __fastcall instead of __cdecl